# Postgresql query between time range

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say i have a table with below data

```
id          shifttime              name
-----+-----------------------+---------------------
  1  |   18:50:00+05:30    |     a
```

Here i want to get the row based on time range, the problem here is that if the end range goes past 24 hrs, i am unable to fetch the row. can any one help me out with the query.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE shifttime>='17:20:00+05:30' AND shifttime<='01:20:00+05:30'
```

Comment: I would say the above is a bad design. Without a date component you have no idea where the shiftime  is. Nor do you really know where the comparison times are anchored.  Turn this into timestamp and remove the uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the comparison as:

```
where (:start < :end and shifttime >= :start AND shifttime <= :end) or
      (:end < :start and not (shifttime >= :start AND shifttime <= :end) )
```

Basically, you need to compare the starting and ending values to determine if you are looking *between* the values or *outside* those values.  Note:  I'm not sure if both end points should be included or not, but that is easily adjusted.

Comment: i did some work around to achieve the same.                                                
```where (:start < :end and shifttime >= :start AND shifttime <= :end) or
      (:end < :start and (shifttime >= :start AND shifttime <= '23:59:99+05:30' OR shifttime >= :'00:00:00+05:30' AND shifttime <= :end  )) ```

Comment: @ranjithkotian . . . That shouldn't be necessary -- although it is possible that the time zone offsets do throw things off a bit.